# How many users hate hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Out of sheer curiosity:

Are there any statistics on how many users click the "I hate hats" button during Winter Bash?

Comment: All I can say is that it wasn't me :)

Comment: Well, I hate hats but it was too much like hard work to move the cursor to the top of the page to disable them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This year there were a total of 215,960 users who participated in hats.  There were also 4,687 users who officially opted out of hats by clicking the 'I Hate Hats' option.  Overall, it is a tiny percent of users who hate hats enough to opt-out of them...only about 2%.

Comment: "participated in hats" - meaning earned at least one hat, or actually wore a hat at least once?

Comment: @ShadowWizard [Earned a hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network).

Comment: Also, after clicking "I Hate Hats" was it possible to opt back in? If so, maybe some did it just for test?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, you can opt out and then opt back in.

Comment: Probably not many, but even if 100 or so opted out then back in, it's interesting extra stat. :)

Comment: I doubt it is even that many - [I clicked the button for dramatic effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6L6j.gif) at the end of that gif, but I was only opted out for a few seconds!